# setting mvc wildcard fix in iis 5.1 through batch commands

Tags: model-view-controller, iis, batch-file, executable

http://www.ee99ee.com/blog/2009/02/08/how-to-get-aspnet-mvc-working-under-iis-51-on-windows-xp/

Can the following be put into batch commands? If not, is there an alternative where the configuration can be set through an executable without the user having to configure through IIS?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to include .aspx into the controller name. so the controller is in the following format 
{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set those properties with the [GET and SET commands of the Adsutil.vbs script](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true) (which [works with IIS 5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525006%28VS.90%29.aspx), would probably be in the directory `C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\`).

I tried a little poking around, and couldn't figure out which keys were needed. But you might be able to figure them out using the Metabase Explorer (from the [IIS 6.0 ResKit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56FC92EE-A71A-4C73-B628-ADE629C89499&displaylang=en), or here is a [third-party version](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1276) which I haven't tried).

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this topic as well and first of all I don't agree with the votes down moderators for a perfectly valid question with research done by the asker. Second the answer is no you cannot put IIS commands in a executable the whole point of IIS is that you set it up once and you are done so just set it up correctly the first time and you should be good also that tutorial you are looking at is rubbish. Just my 2 cents!